# Change Single Select to Multiple Select Google Map API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, multi-select

I'm trying to change the single select box to multiple select.  I changed the select to include multiple, but when I click multiple selections, none of the markers show up on the Google Map. I'm struggling with how to bind the selections to the sites array that contain the locations. How can Implement a multi select box within the code?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=Edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
      </head>
  <div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

      <div align ="center" class ="input-w">
          <div class ="gulf">States</div>

   <fieldset>
    <div class = "flexi">
          <label>ISE: </label> 
          <select id ="ISEs" multiple class="dropdown" name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers(); centerMap()">
             <option value="0">All</option>
             <option  value="Bob">Bob</option>
             <option value="Sally">Sally</option>

         </select><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
           </fieldset>
        </div> 
    <div id="map"></div>

        <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.25.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"onerror = "googleError()"
></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.JS

```
var sites= [

{name:"ABC",address:"123",lat:"29.97046",lng:"-92.09689",SalesPerson:"Bob"},
{name:"DEF",address:"123",lat:"30.97046",lng:"-92.09689",SalesPerson:"Bob"},
{name:"GHI",address:"123",lat:"31.97046",lng:"-92.09689",SalesPerson:"Sally"},
{name:"JKL",address:"123",lat:"32.97046",lng:"-92.09689",SalesPerson:"Sally"},

];

//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.340803,-89.4855946),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

      $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var icons = {
                Bob: {
                  icon:  { 
                    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png" 
                 } 
                },
                Sally: {
                    icon:  { 
                      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png" 
                   } 
                  }
            }

    var createMarker = function (info) {

        var features = [
            {
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat,info.lng),
              type: info.SalesPerson
            }
        ]
        for (var i =0; i < features.length; i++)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: features[i].position,
            icon:icons[features[i].type].icon,
            title: info.name,

        });

        marker.content = '<div class="iw-ISE">' + info.ISE + '</div>'
        + '<div class="iw-labels">' + "Contact: "+ info.Contact + '</div>'
       + '<div class="iw-labels">' + "Store Phone: "+ info.Phone + '</div>'
             +'<p>'+ info.address +'</p>'

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2 class ="title">' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
        createMarker(sites[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

    $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
        $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      $scope.markers.length = 0;
    }
        $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
       //1.select filtered cities
       var filteredISE;
       var ISEName = $scope.data.singleSelect;
       if(ISEName == '0') {
          filteredISE = sites;
       }
       else {
          filteredISE = sites.filter(function(c){
            if(c.SalesPerson == ISEName)
               return c; 
          });
       }  
       //2.update markers on map
       $scope.clearMarkers();
       for (i = 0; i < filteredISE.length; i++) {
        createMarker(filteredISE[i]);
       }
    }



     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote my pen with Angular Js, here is the link codepen.io/ueple/full/ExjaXjL , tell me if it's ok for you ?, or is there's something I've missed ! :-)

Comment: That's great.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

After reading your scope, I create an example in Js, not Angularjs like, but with some functionalities you're expecting, I hope so. Tell me if it helps you.

[My codePen](https://codepen.io/ueple/full/bGNJjry)

What i'm using is an Array of Places and Markers that are read with the function
initalizeMaps.

```
var mapPlaces      = {
                  id1: {town: 'Decines Charpieu', lat: 45.767000, lng: 4.950000, zoom: 14, display: 1},
                  id2: {town: 'Paris', lat: 48.851208, lng: 2.348436, zoom: 10, display: 2},
                  id3: {town: 'New York', lat: 40.748294, lng: -73.985858, zoom: 11, display: 1},
                  id4: {town: 'Rio de Janeiro', lat: -22.974772, lng: -43.185066, zoom: 8, display: 2},
                  id5: {town: 'City of Athena', lat: 37.980549, lng: 23.725121, zoom: 10, display: 1}
                 };
```

and

```
var mapMarkers     = [ 
                   {id: 1,title: 'My town', desc: 'A town of 25000 inhabitants', lat: 45.768811, lng: 4.955300, icon: 'reddot', extraTitle: 'My town Extra Infos', extraDesc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor ante ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean commodo mi nec nisl cursus mollis. Nam tortor elit, suscipit vitae tellus at, suscipit pretium metus. Aenean id ultrices ligula. In non dui et magna placerat semper ut et tellus. Ut purus nulla, malesuada a ante malesuada, rhoncus vulputate diam.', url: "https://www.decines-charpieu.fr/uploads/Image/41/IMF_DIAPORAMA_ACCUEIL/GAB_REFONTE/6313_606_Ville-Cuturel.jpg"}];
```

And the function to read those 2 Arrays is

```
function initializeMap(idMap)
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap( currentMap ));
```

Regards

Comment: I am wanting a way to select multiple names in the drop down box, so that it filters the markers to those names.  Now only one name at a time filters. I didn't see a way to do that in your code and pen.  Please let me know if you have a way to accomplish. Thx!

Comment: Hi Ginger22, sorry for being so long ;-). I've my codePen, if you can have a look to what I've add. If you try in the markers list to select a name you will see the selected one bounce, and so on. Tell me if it helps you. Hope so ! Regards. Pascal

Comment: Hi.  Thx for updating this.  Really nice map btw.  But what I'm after is a filter.  What I am needing is a way to select multiple items in the drop down and have it filter to just those items.  The items that are not selected would not be visible. I see that they bounce in the pen, which is really cool, but do you have a way to filter?  This will be a map with hundreds of locations, so I need a way to select multiple names in the drop down and only show those markers that are selected. Right now I can only select one item at a time that filters. Hope that was clear.  TY!

Comment: Hi Ginger22, I've changed my pen to show, when you click in the Markers List, only the one selected, or If you select more than one item in the list, only those selected. Is it right or wrong for you ? Pascal. The new link for my Pen https://codepen.io/ueple/full/LYVYjbR

Comment: Yes, that looks great.  Do you have an easy way to make that work with the code I submitted in the question?

Comment: Hi Ginger22, I re-wrote my pen with Angular Js, here is the link https://codepen.io/ueple/full/ExjaXjL , tell me if it's ok for you ?, or is there's something I've missed ! :-) .